# Reading endpoint from config file

Tags: wcf

How do I obtain the endpointIdentity from the config file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could load up your web.config file using WebConfigurationManager, get the `<client>` section, and then find the appropriate `<endpoint>` element (by name or by address or whatever) and then drill into it to find the DNS value:

```
ClientSection clientSection = (WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as ClientSection);

foreach(ChannelEndpointElement cee in clientSection.Endpoints)
{
    if(cee.Name == "ConfigurationManagerTcp")
    {
        IdentityElement ie = cee.Identity;

        string dnsValue = ie.Dns.Value;
    }
}
```

You'll need to use the `System.Web.Configuration` and `System.ServiceModel.COnfiguration` namespaces for the classes involved.

Marc